# Count post + add number =

Tags: count

I'm having problems with counting posts of a custom post type called 'projects' and like to add a number to the count. We did some stuff which can't be shown in our portfolio but would like to add only as number.

Basically it goes as follow:

There are 22 published projects (custom posts type called 'projects') + 11 other projects (no posts) = echo 33 projects.

Edit:

I'm using this to get the wordpress counts:

```
<?php
            $count_posts = wp_count_posts('projects');
            $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
            ?>

<?php // echo $published_posts  ?>
```

How do I get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 22 projects are _published_ posts from the `projects` CPT? What are the 11 others? Unpublished posts? Planned projects with no presence in the DB? What?

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum they are created projects but not in the database (and will never be).

Comment: So how are you tracking them? You just want a count of posts plus a static number?

Comment: I've editted my post question. I'm counting already the wordpress posts but need to add a static number (11) to count the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count posts of some custom post type, you can try out the WordPress function `wp_count_posts()`

In your case the custom post type is `'projects'` so you might try this:

```
$count_projects = wp_count_posts( 'projects' );
$published_projects = $count_projects->publish;
$total = $published_projects + 11; // include your additional projects
```

You can read more about this function in the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts).